# Prediction using sklearn's RandomForestRegressor

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, random-forest

Probably a very dumb question so be easy on me, but here I go.

So here's what my data looks like...

```
date,locale,category,site,alexa_rank,sessions,user_logins
20170110,US,1,google,1,500,5000
20170110,EU,1,google,2,400,2000
20170111,US,2,facebook,2,400,2000
```

... and so on. This is just a toy dataset I came up with, but which resembles the original data.

I'm trying to build a model to predict how many user logins and sessions a particular site would have, using sklearn's `RandomForestRegressor`.

I do the usual stuff, encoding categories to labels and I've trained my model on the first eight months of the year and now I'd like to predict logins and sessions for the ninth month. I've created one model trained on logins and another one trained on sessions.

My test dataset is of the same form:

```
date,locale,category,site,alexa_rank,sessions,user_logins
20170910,US,1,google,1,500,5000
20170910,EU,1,google,2,400,2000
20170911,US,2,facebook,2,400,2000
```

Ideally I'd like to pass in the test dataset *without* the columns I need predicted, but RandomForestRegressor complains about the dimensions being different between the training and test set.

When I pass the test dataset in its current form, the model predicts the *exact* values in the `sessions` and `user_logins` columns in most cases and values with tiny variations otherwise.

I zeroed out the  `sessions` and `user_logins` columns in the test data and passed it to the model but the model predicted nearly all zeroes.

- Is my workflow correct? Am I using RandomForestRegressor correctly?
- How am I getting so close to the actual values when my test dataset does contain actual values? Are the actual values in the test data being used in the prediction?
- If the model works correctly, shouldn't I be getting the same values predicted if I zero out the columns I'm looking to predict (`sessions` and `user_logins`)?

Comment: Can you add your code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't pass the column you want to predict in the test data. You workflow is not correct.

If `X` is the set of columns of the information you have,
if `y` is the set of columns of the information you want to predict,
then you should pass (`X_train`, `y_train`) during the training (using the method `fit`), and (`X_test`, ) only during the testing (using the method `predict`). You will obtain `y_pred` that you can compare with `y_test` if you have it.

In your example, if you want to predict `user_logins`:

```py
X_train = array([['20170110', 'US', '1', 'google', '1', '500'],
                 ['20170110', 'EU', '1', 'google', '2', '400'],
                 ['20170111', 'US', '2', 'facebook', '2', '400']],
                dtype='<U21')
y_train = array(['5000', '2000', '2000'], dtype='<U21')

X_test = array([['20170112', 'EU', '2', 'google', '1', '500'],
                ['20170113', 'US', '1', 'facebook', '2', '400'],
                ['2017014', 'US', '2', 'google', '1', '500']],
               dtype='<U21')

estimator = RandomForestRegressor().fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = estimator.predict(X_test)
```

Take a look at the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html) for more examples, or at the [tutorials](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/basic/tutorial.html#learning-and-predicting).

Comment: Please add an example of what you mean by X_train and y_train using the OP's data.